# Sqoop Fails to Import from Postgres to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, sqoop, data-ingestion

I import data from Postgresql to hdfs and hdfs to S3 in my daily operation. (sqoop import [postgres to hdfs] & distcp [from hdfs to s3])

I wanted to remove intermediate step (hdfs) and directly import data to S3 bucket by using sqoop.

However, same sqoop string fails in the end of the import operation.

```
sqoop import 
-Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb="8192" 
-Dmapreduce.map.java.opts="-Xmx7200m" 
-Dmapreduce.task.timeout=0 
-Dmapreduce.task.io.sort.mb="2400" 
--connect $conn_string$ 
--fetch-size=20000 
--username $user_name$ 
--p $password$ 
--num-mappers 20 
--query "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.id > 10000000 and table1.id < 20000000 and \$CONDITIONS" 
--hcatalog-database $schema_name$ 
--hcatalog-table $table_name$ 
--hcatalog-storage-stanza "STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION s3a://path/to/destination"
--split-by table1.id
```

I also tried `--target-dir s3a://path/to/destination` instead of  `....... LOCATION s3a://path/to/destination`

After "mapping: %100 completed" it throws error message below:

````
Error: java.io.IOException: Could not clean up TaskAttemptID:attempt_1571557098082_15536_m_000004_0@s3a://path/to/destination_DYN0.6894861001907555/ingest_day=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.TaskCommitContextRegistry.commitTask(TaskCommitContextRegistry.java:83)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileOutputCommitterContainer.commitTask(FileOutputCommitterContainer.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.commit(Task.java:1200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.done(Task.java:1062)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:345)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not rename 
s3a://path/to/destination/_DYN0.6894861001907555/ingest_day=20180522/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1571557098082_15536_m_000004_0 
to 
s3a://path/to/destination/_DYN0.6894861001907555/ingest_day=20180522/_temporary/1/task_1571557098082_15536_m_000004
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:579)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCommitter.commitTask(OutputCommitter.java:343)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.DynamicPartitionFileRecordWriterContainer$1.commitTask(DynamicPartitionFileRecordWriterContainer.java:125)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.TaskCommitContextRegistry.commitTask(TaskCommitContextRegistry.java:80)
        ... 9 more```
````

Comment: Looks like permission issues. Sqoop imports data to a temp directory while job is running. At the end it tries to rename data files. Ideally sqoop should have required permission to rename the files.
Could not rename 
s3a://path/to/destination/_DYN0.6894861001907555/ingest_day=20180522/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1571557098082_15536_m_000004_0 
to 
s3a://path/to/destination/_DYN0.6894861001907555/ingest_day=20180522/_temporary/1/task_1571557098082_15536_m_000004

Refer: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/changing-temp-directory-in-sqoop-import/td-p/281969

Comment: @yammanuruarun thanks for the response. You're right and this issue has been resolved on Sqoop 1.4.7.* where we're using 1.4.6.*

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop tries to rename the S3 folder after import job is completed which is not possible due to the architecture of S3 which is object storage.

I found out that this issue has been resolved in Sqoop 1.4.7.*